# Facebook API : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: asp.net

After i had wrote the following code  and run

```
    using Facebook;
    using System.Dynamic;

    FacebookClient fp= new FacebookClient( My access_token );

   Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   dic["message"] = "Helloooooo";

   fb.Post("/me",dic);
```

this exception occurred :

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

so if you please can you help me to fix this issue ?

any reply will be appreciated